# I had never tried pomegranate until now

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

The past perfect is used to talk about an earlier past situation of two past situations.

Supposing I started trying pomegranate a few seconds ago.
Would it be natural in this case to say "I had never tried pomegranate until now."? Or should I say "I have never tried pomegranate until now." while I'm munching pomegranate?

Answer (score 0):

As that past situation relates to almost the present moment, just a few seconds ago, the present perfect is suitable.

> I have never tried pomegranate until now.

Comment: And then, a moment later and forever after, it’s the past perfect that is suitable: “I **had** never tried pomegranate until just then,” and a bit later “…a few minutes ago,” and then “…earlier today,” etc.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum sorry, I don't get it. Do you disagree with the answer?

Comment: Maybe I am disagreeing slightly. In any case, the instant the trying has been completed, present perfect stops being possible.

Comment: Do you disagree with what is said in this video from 3:17 to 5:15? The link: https://youtu.be/iLcAdXlid0w?si=GR1I-KlrMTn3969w